# Можно ли получить письма по IMAP Gmail?

Tags: gmail, imap

Можно ли получить все письма по IMAP? Или эту возможность закрыли и теперь только использовать API и OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Можно. По крайней мере, у меня почтовая программа получает.

Сервер: imap.gmail.com
Имя пользователя без @gmail.com
Log on using clear text authentication